# Starting a container on a Kubernetes cluster from another container

Tags: python, kubernetes, containers

I have two docker containers as follows:

1. A web server coded in python
2. A python script which performs a computational activity and then terminates

I want to be able to have the web server start the computation script contained in container two. The cluster is being controlled by Kubernetes.

My initial thought is to have the web server signal to Kubernetes to start the computation container. However, there may be alternative and better ways to achieve this.

It may also be possible to use a job queue to line up jobs which Kubernetes polls and starts pods when required.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does the web server need to be able to know that the jobs have finished, and look at their output the same way it would if it were running them locally, or are they just "fire and forget?" There are *a lot* of job running projects that integrate with k8s, but the amount of pain in setting them up and the features they offer differ wildly

Comment: Hello, you could spawn a `Pod` with your web server that will have tools/permissions to communicate with Kubernetes API to schedule/watch Jobs. You will need to have correct RBAC permissions and library to communicate with the API of your choosing. Here are some links for additional reference: [Setting RBAC permissions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/), [Kubernetes Python client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python).

Answer (score 1):

> My initial thought is to have the web server signal to Kubernetes to start the computation container. However, there may be alternative and better ways to achieve this.

One of the possible ways for this to work would be to:

- Create a `ServiceAccount`.
- Assign specific permissions to your `ServiceAccount` to support your workload (listing jobs, creating jobs, deleting jobs, etc.)
- Bind your `Role` to a `ServiceAccount`
- Run your `web-server` with earlier created `ServiceAccount`
- Query the Kubernetes API.

Some of the things to take into consideration:

- You will need `kubectl` binary or `Kubernetes API Python library` inside of a `web-server`.
- You will need to consider the storage options for the results of your computational python script.

  - As an example: [Matthewpalmer.net: Example NFS Persistent Volumes](https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/kubernetes-volumes-example-nfs-persistent-volume.html)

---

I've pasted the links I provided in the comment for better visibility:

- *[Setting RBAC permissions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)*
- *[Kubernetes Python client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python)*

Also to add I found this article with similar setup:

- *[Blog.meain.io: Accessing Kubernetes API from pod](https://blog.meain.io/2019/accessing-kubernetes-api-from-pod/)*

---

As for an example of such setup:

#### Create a `ServiceAccount`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: python-job-sa
```

This `ServiceAccount` will be used with the `Deployment/Pod` that will host your `web-server`.

#### Assign specific permissions to your `ServiceAccount`

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: python-job-role
rules:
# This will give you access to jobs
- apiGroups: ["batch", "extensions"]
  resources: ["jobs"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
# This will give you access to pods
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
# This will give you access to pods logs
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/log"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
```

This is a `Role` that allows to query the Kubernetes API for the resources like `Jobs`.

#### Bind your `Role` to a `ServiceAccount`

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: python-job-rolebinding
  namespace: default
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: python-job-sa 
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: Role 
  name: python-job-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

This `RoleBinding` will bind your `ServiceAccount` to your `Role` and will allow to communicate with Kubernetes API.

> A tip!
>
> To isolate the workload, you can use namespace different than `default` (you will need to have a `ServiceAccount`, `Role` and `RoleBinding` in the same namespace)!

#### Run your `web-server` with earlier created `ServiceAccount`

For the **example**/**testing** purposes the `google/cloud-sdk:latest` image was used. It already has `kubectl` and `python` installed.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cloud-sdk-job
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cloud-sdk-job
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cloud-sdk-job
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: python-job-sa # <-- IMPORTANT    
      containers:
      - name: cloud-sdk
        image: google/cloud-sdk:latest
        command: 
        - sleep
        - "infinity"
```

#### Query the Kubernetes API

Querying should be done by your `web-server` but for an example purpose you can exec into the running `Pod` and check if the python script to run a `Job` is running correctly:

- `$ kubectl exec -it WEB-SERVER-POD-NAME -- /bin/bash`

> Disclaimer!
>
> `google/cloud-sdk:latest` requires kubernetes python api library to be installed with pip:
>
> - `$ pip3 install kubernetes`

The example code to spawn a `Job`:

```py
from kubernetes import client, config

JOB_NAME = "example-job" 
def create_job_object():
    # Configureate Pod template container
    container = client.V1Container(
        name="pi",
        image="perl",
        command=["perl", "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(2000)"])
    # Create and configurate a spec section
    template = client.V1PodTemplateSpec(
        metadata=client.V1ObjectMeta(labels={"app": "pi"}),
        spec=client.V1PodSpec(restart_policy="Never", containers=[container]))
    # Create the specification of deployment
    spec = client.V1JobSpec(
        template=template,
        backoff_limit=4)
    # Instantiate the job object
    job = client.V1Job(
        api_version="batch/v1",
        kind="Job",
        metadata=client.V1ObjectMeta(name=JOB_NAME),
        spec=spec)

    return job

def create_job(api_instance, job):
    # Create job
    api_response = api_instance.create_namespaced_job(
        body=job,
        namespace="default")
    print("Job created. status='%s'" % str(api_response.status))

def main():
    # Configs can be set in Configuration class directly or using helper
    # utility. If no argument provided, the config will be loaded from
    # default location.

    # config.load_kube_config()
    config.load_incluster_config() # <-- IMPORTANT
    batch_v1 = client.BatchV1Api()

    # Create a job object with client-python API. The job we
    job = create_job_object()

    create_job(batch_v1, job)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

> Above example is from the Kubernetes Python API library:
>
> *[Github.com: Kubernetes client: Python: Examples](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/tree/master/examples)*

Checking if the `Job` was scheduled and completed:

```sh
NAME          COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
example-job   1/1           9s         10m
```

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Authorization overview](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/)*